# Edit Minecraft .dat File in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, minecraft

I'm looking to edit a Minecraft Windows 10 `level.dat` file in python. I've tried using the package `nbt` and `pyanvil` but get the error `OSError: Not a gzipped file`. If I print `open("level.dat", "rb").read()` I get a lot of nonsensical data. It seems like it needs to be decoded somehow, but I don't know what decoding it needs. How can I open (and ideally edit) one of these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read data just do :

```
from nbt import nbt

nbtfile = nbt.NBTFile("level.dat", 'rb')
print(nbtfile) # Here you should get a TAG_Compound('Data')
print(nbtfile["Data"].tag_info()) # Data came from the line above
for tag in nbtfile["Data"].tags: # This loop will show us each entry 
    print(tag.tag_info())
```

As for editing :

```
# Writing data (changing the difficulty value
nbtfile["Data"]["Difficulty"].value = 2
print(nbtfile["Data"]["Difficulty"].tag_info())
nbtfile.write_file("level.dat")
```

> EDIT:
>
> It looks like Mojang doesn't use the same formatting for Java and bedrock, as bedrock's level.dat file is stored in little endian format and uses non-compressed UTF-8.
> As an alternative, [Amulet-Nbt](https://amulet-nbt.readthedocs.io/en/3.0) is supposed to be a Python library written in Cython for reading and editing NBT files (supposedly works with Bedrock too).
> Nbtlib also seems to work, as long as you set `byteorder="little` when loading the file.

Let me know if u need more help...

Comment: I still get nonsensical data. I'm not sure how minecraft and world editors decode minecraft .dat files, but we're still missing something.

Comment: Ah I see okay, I'll edit my response

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work: `gzip.BadGzipFile: Not a gzipped file (b'\x08\x00')`

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: My code is exactly what you posted!

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with your level.dat file ? Did u try generating a new one and tried the code with it ?

Comment: Yes, I already tried that. If it helps, I'm using Minecraft for Windows 10 version 1.19.

Comment: Okay, could you please share with me the file, so that I can try to read it ?

Comment: Of course! [Here is the link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IoIHsJEf5iF7QA17xygfaocQhR6_0HyW/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is very weird, I tried opening the file with NBTExplorer which is a tool designed to open NBT files but it failed. I then Tried to read your nbt file using python and I got an error stating that the Compound Tag is missing... The file actually gets read if you just read it normally (not in binary mode) which SHOULD NOT be the case. The only conclusion I have so far is that maybe your level.dat is corrupted ? Have you tried loading it ? Does it load normally into the game ? I will compare it to a brand one that I generate and see if it gets fixed. Will keep you posted.

Comment: Okay so here's what I found, looks like Mojang don't use the same formatting for Java and bedrock as in bedrock level.dat is stored in little endian format and uses non-compressed UTF-8. So you need an alternative, I found something called Amulet-Nbt which is supposed to be Python Library written in Cython for reading and editing NBT files (supposedly works with Bedrock too) here are the docs : https://amulet-nbt.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/
I recommend using their tool amulet for editing the world, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: That's it! Opening the file in little endian mode without decompressing it seems to do the trick. I'm trying the package `nbtlib` because it's written in plain python (so I can modify it if I want), but it seems like amulet-nbt works as well. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I was able to help Good luck with the rest !

Answer (score -2):

You'll have to give the path either relative to the current working directory

> path/to/file.dat

Or you can use the absolute path to the file

> C:user/dir/path/to/file.dat

Read the data,replace the values and then write it

```
# Read in the file
with open('file.dat', 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()

# Replace the target string
filedata = filedata.replace('yuor replacement or edit')

# Write the file out again
with open('file.dat', 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the insight, but I still get nonsensical data. I'm not sure exactly how minecraft and other editors decode minecraft .dat files, but I'm still missing something.